# Volume element under change of variables

Tags: calculus, functions, change-of-variable

Consider the following function:
$$f(q, p)=a\left[(b \cdot q)^{2}+(c \cdot p)^{2}-1\right] e^{-(b \cdot q)^{2}-(c \cdot p)^{2}}$$
with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to express it in terms of $x\equiv b \cdot q,\ y\equiv c \cdot p$. How do I take into account the volume element under change of variables?

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:algebra-precalculus] or with [tag:algebraic-geometry]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, you can edit the question if you feel the tags are inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to simplify the given expression  $(q,p)\mapsto f(q,p)$ you introduced new variables $x$, $y$ via $$x:=b\,q,\quad y:=c\,p\ .\tag{1}$$ This means that you in fact parametrize the $(q,p)$-plane by an auxiliary map
$$\psi:\quad(x,y)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{q&=x/b\cr p&=y/c \cr}\right.\quad\ .$$
(Your momentary troubles stem from the fact that the given formulas $(1)$ do not describe $\psi$, but its inverse $\psi^{-1}$.)

You now have the pullback
$$\hat f:=f\circ\psi:\quad(x,y)\mapsto \hat f(x,y)= f\left({x\over b},{y\over c}\right)\ ,$$
which computes to
$$\hat f(x,y)=a(x^2+y^2-1)e^{-x^2-y^2}\ ,$$
as originally desired. So far no "volume correction" is necessary.

Now it can be that a domain $B$ in the $(q,p)$-plane is given, and you want to compute the integral
$$\int_B f(q,p)\>{\rm d}(q,p)\ .$$
It is possible to convert this integral to an integral concerning the pullback $\hat f$. To this end we need the description of the domain $\hat B:=\psi^{-1}(B)$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, that is transformed by $\psi$ into the given $B$, and we need the Jacobian $J_\psi(x,y)={1\over bc}$. The general transformation formula then says that
$$\int_B f(q,p)\>{\rm d}(q,p)=\int_{\hat B}\hat f(x,y)|J_\psi(x,y)|\>{\rm d}(x,y)={1\over|bc|}\int_{\hat B}a(x^2+y^2-1)e^{-x^2-y^2}\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I understand from you answer, the volume correction is not necessary if I only want to transform the function without carrying out any integral. But that is exactly what my professor claims. I want to change $f(q, p) \rightarrow f(x, y)$ and plot the function in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @JKalle: What I have written is correct. But it may be that, dependent on the application, one introduces additional definitions, e.g., one replaces $\hat f$ by $g:={1\over|bc|}\hat f$, so that the "corrected pullback" might become a probability density function, etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer and clarification.